# How to use python in a JS based app

Tags: javascript, python

I have created an app using meteor.js framework. I need to run some python code for some important data crunching that will be used in the app. How can I do that? I am really new to Javascript and cant figure this out. I will be running python code on server. All I need is, as soon as I click a particular button, a piece of python code gets compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to expose your Python code over some sort of API. Since your Python is "running on the server" as you mentioned.

The fastest way I can think of doing it is to setup an AWS Lambda function (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/), then expose it as an API route using AWS API Gateway(https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/).

Once your "number crunching" is completed, you'll need to return the relevant variables back to your client app. JSON is probably a good choice for this.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this than to setup api? Can't I call python code from Javascript or something else that is simple and fast to do?

Comment: You could have the (server-side) meteor and the python on the same filesystem and pass information across the stdout, or pass data with a rabbitMQ or Redis, but you said "simple and fast", which is why I recommended the AWS solution. You also lose some extensibility by assuming them always on the same filesystem.

Comment: There is going to be bit of a learning curve if Pyhton is all you have. Using AWS is a good suggestion, Django is a possibility albiet heavy handed (had to do this once).  If simplicity is your goal, another server side language and stack might be your best bet.  I'm assuming you are deploying to a  unix like environment.  If so and PHP is available it would be a quick way to write the service that handles the request.  You could write the logic in PHP but if you had a Python module already written instead of porting it you could shell out to it.  If you don't know PHP, I'd start with AWS.